# Can't write on hard drive owned by user and with permissions to write, read and execute

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I am very puzzled by this problem I am having. I am trying to execute a file in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via command line. I have a script that calls a program to run and write the results in a hard drive. I changed the permissions and ownership of everything to be wxr. Here is the ls -l of my script (called TEST-star):

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root       950 Nov 15 13:16 TEST-star
```

Here is the ls -l of the package my script calls:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  1931414 Nov 10 12:37 STAR
```

Finally the ls -l of the hard drive mounted in /media/CLC"

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8192 Nov 15 13:04 CLC
```

I have been trying to run it since yesterday and always get a message that I don't have permission to write the results:

```
EXITING because of FATAL ERROR: could not create output file ./_STARtmp//Unmapped.out.mate1.thread14
Solution: check that you have permission to write this file
```

I thought if I change the permissions to rwx and run my script as root it would not have a problem (using sudo). Right now I run out of options. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Please let me know what other information you would need solve this issue.
Thank you. 
Here is the first line of script I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /media/CLC/ANOPHELES-STAR-v2.4f1/; mkdir GambFemAnt1 && cd GambFemAnt1;  echo $PWD && echo Starting mapping of GambFemAnt1; /home/aedes/Documents/STAR_2.4.0f1/STAR --genomeDir /media/Galaxy/Galaxy_data/Anopheles/STAR/Genome --readFilesIn /media/Galaxy/Galaxy_data/Anopheles/QC/GambFemAnt1/GambFemAnt1.fastq --runThreadN 23 --outFilterMismatchNmax 4 --outFilterMatchNminOverLread 0.75 --seedSearchLmax 30 --seedSearchStartLmax 30 --seedPerReadNmax 100000 --seedPerWindowNmax 100 --alignTranscriptsPerReadNmax 100000 --alignTranscriptsPerWindowNmax 10000 --outSAMstrandField intronMotif --outFilterIntronMotifs RemoveNoncanonical --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --outReadsUnmapped Fastx; mv Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam GambFemAnt1.bam; mv Unmapped.out.mate1 GambFemAnt1-unmapped.fastq; cp *.fastq /media/CLC/ANOPHELES-STAR-v2.4f1/UNMAPED-reads/; cd /media/CLC/ANOPHELES-STAR-v2.4f1 && echo $PWD && echo GambFemAnt1 mapping finished;
```

I also posted a question for the authors of the package.

Comment: What directory are you running the script from?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right path? That error message suggests that you are trying to write to a file in the same directory as your script.

Comment: First I tried run it from the hard drive I am trying to write the data. Then I moved it to /home/user/Documents and tried to run from there. In this script I have a mkdir command and it works.

Comment: Well when I run the script I see the directory being created and all the 5 files it should create within that directory. Let me double check anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MikeW I was thinking why I was getting this ./_STARtmp//Unmapped.out.mate1.thread14. I remembered to see someone have an issue with this software when they were trying to run it with more than 6 threads. I changed my script to use only 12 threads instead of 23 and it works. So the permissions were correct. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all the permissions were set correctly. The problem resigns within the package. I found out that it works using  `--runThreadN 12` instead of  `--runThreadN 23.`